# Create a method sum() and another method numEven()

Tags: java

***I have to calculate the sum of all the even numbers via an array.***

In my exercise I am obliged to have two methods:

the first method is **sum()** and the second **numEven()**.

I have an array below:

```
int[] array1 = {10,15,23,12,69,21,16,54};
```

My method **sum()** seems to be correct:

```
public static int sum(int[] array){
    int number_sum = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      number_sum += array[i];
    }
    return number_sum;
}
```

However, I have several problems with my method **numEven()**

I think that use a string is not good?

```
public static String numEven(int[] array){
    String evenNumbers = "";
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
      }
    }
    return evenNumbers;      
 }
```

Then, in my print() I have this:

```
System.out.println("The resultat is => " + sum(numEven(array1)));
```

My error message is:

```
Main.java:23: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to int[]
```

Do know you how to do a better method to find the even numbers?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `numEven` should receive an `int` and return a `boolean` and you should call it from `sum`. Use it to determine if a member of the array is even and only then add it to the sum

Comment: Are you asking for `numEven` to delete all but even numbers from the list?

Comment: @MAO3J1m0Op: Ehhh no...

Comment: What are you trying to do ? and what is your question ?@user11124425

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in this piece of code:

```
sum(numEven(array1))
```

First you calling `numEven` which returns String and then pass it as an argument to the `sum` method.

To make it work - change `numEven` method to return `int[]` array.

One of the ways is:

```
public static int[] numEven(int[] array) {
    List<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
            evenNumbers.add(array[i]);
        }
    }

    int[] result = new int[evenNumbers.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < evenNumbers.size(); i++) {
        result[i] = evenNumbers.get(i);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to keep the signature of numEven as you posted it (i.e, it should receive an array of int), then you have one of two methods:

1- you iterate over the array and create a new array of only even numbers and then call sum function to use it.

2- you iterate over the array and only add even numbers.

I'm putting here the solutions using the first method as it is better to use the sum code you already made.

Your code has a problem as it assumes it will use a string to add numbers.

```
public static int numEven(int[] array){
    ArrayList<Integer> evenNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
      if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
          evenNumbers.add(array[i]);
      }
    }
    return sum(evenNumbers.toArray());      
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a String to a method that takes an int[] public static int sum(int[] array).

In your case, I would consider using an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). An ArrayList is an object that is similar to an array but which you can add values to at any point. With an array, once you set the values, you can't change them, but with an ArrayList, you can keep adding values at any time.

First at the very top of your program, you need to import the ArrayList class from the java.util library:

```
import java.util.ArrayList
```

Next, here's what your numEven would look like:

```
public static int[] numEven(int[] array){
ArrayList<int> evens = new ArrayList<int>();
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
  if(array[i] % 2 == 0){
     evens.add(array[i]);
  }
}
return evens.toArray();      
}
```

ArrayList initializes a new ArrayList of type int. evens.add() adds a value to the ArrayList. Notice at the end we have to return evens.toArray(), which converts the ArrayList back to a normal array of type int, because sum() is expecting an array of type int, and *not* an ArrayList.